# How to align one flex child as flex-start and other in center?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a sidebar that is set to flex with direction column. I am trying to get my menu `ul` to be vertically centered, and my `.logo-container` to be on the top of the page.

Is there any way to get one child to flex-start and another one centered?

Code:

```
<aside class="side-bar">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html" class="link">
          <img src="http://unsplash.it/30/30" class="logoimg" alt="">
          <h6 class="logoname">My<span class="lastname">Name</span></h6>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem1</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem2</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem3</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 100%;
}

.logoname {
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/thephilgrim/pen/qBXQeJJ)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to have the logo and ul in separate divs within the parent div that has the column direction styling, apply **flex-shrink:0** to the div containing the logo and **flex-grow: 1** to the other div.

That will allow the logo to be at the top and the other div to take the rest of the space - then you can apply flex styling in the navigation -container to center the ul within that div.

UPDATE - the OP wanted the ul centered into the height of the viewport - as noted in the comments this is as simple as offsetting the position of the ul in the bottom div by half the height of the top div - so in this case - moving it up by 20px) because the top div is 40px in height. This allows centering of the ul into the viewport height without resorting to adding empty divs just to get the alignment.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 8px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-container {
 flex-shrink:0
}

.logoname {
  display: inline-block;
  padding : 8px;
    color: lime;
}

.navigation-container {
 flex-grow:1;
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px
}
li a{ color: white; }
```

```html
<aside class="side-bar">
    <nav class="navigation">
    
      <div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html" class="link">
          <img src="http://unsplash.it/30/30" class="logoimg" alt="">
          <h6 class="logoname">My<span class="lastname">Name</span></h6>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation-container">
        <ul class="nav-list">
          <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem1</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem2</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem3</a></li>
          <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </aside>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't that then mean that the menu ul is not vertically centered, since its div is not taking up 100% of the vertical space. The ul would only be centered within its div. In other words, it would push the menu slightly down?

Comment: true - the ul is cerntered into the second div - to allow the offset from the first div - yyiu can move the ul up by half the height of the top div. The top div is 40px high - so its as simple as using translate-y or position: relative; top: -20px to move the ul up by haldf the high of the header div - and so it wlll be centered vertically into the height of the viewport. Solution update to show this. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create an empty/invisible element as a third flex item inside the flex parent (in my example below it's the `div`with class `xxx`) and apply `justify-content: space-between` to the flex parent (instead of `center`).

Depending on your actual code and content you should make sure that that additional element has the same height as the `nav` element (30px in your and my example). And again, depending on the situation you might want to add `visibility: hidden;` to the additional element (`xxx`) to make it invisible but still have its height included in the `flex` position calculations:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.logoname {
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.xxx {
  height: 30px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<aside class="side-bar">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <div class="logo-container">
      <a href="index.html" class="link">
        <img src="http://unsplash.it/30/30" class="logoimg" alt="">
        <h6 class="logoname">My<span class="lastname">Name</span></h6>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem1</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem2</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem3</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="xxx"></div>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 35%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  height: 100%;
}



* {
  color: black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.logo-container {
  display:grid;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  }

.logo-container img {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  }
```

```html
<aside class="side-bar">
<div class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html" class="link">
          <img src="http://unsplash.it/30/30" class="logoimg" alt="">
          <h6 class="logoname">My<span class="lastname">Name</span></h6>
        </a>
      </div>
    <nav class="navigation">
      
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem1</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem2</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem3</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#" class="link">Menuitem4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </aside>
```